# What is actually the scripting name or the language name use in Sharepoint list column validation?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, column-validation

What is actually the scripting name or the language name use in Sharepoint list column validation?
Is there any text or code editor available for the scripting?

Answer (score 0):

In general, as far as scripting is concerned in SharePoint, the core scripting language is javascript. 
The code editor you can as notepad, notepad++ or any online editors like https://jsfiddle.net/, https://jseditor.io/, https://paiza.io/en/languages/javascript, etc.

And as far as column validation is concerned in SharePoint, we use some logical expressions where we use comparison between columns value and up to some extend use the HTML formating,so no concept of scripting here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular name of the language used in SharePoint List/List Column Validation or Calculated column formulas.

But, Microsoft SharePoint formulas for calculated fields and list validation formulas are **based on Microsoft Excel functions and syntax**.

Also there is a very helpful article on Creating Calculated Column Formulas the Easy Way Using Excel:

[SharePoint: Creating Calculated Column Formulas the Easy Way Using Excel](https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-creating-calculated-column.html)

**Code Editor**:

There is no particular code editor which will give you any intellisense or syntax error while building SharePoint formulas. It is totally based on using the correct formula/function syntaxes (refer below reference link) and column names. However you can use any code editor to write your formula and then copy paste it into SharePoint.

**Reference**:

[Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Hi @Nas, does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help others in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement,the following is an list of links to functions available to SharePoint users. It includes trigonomic, statistical, and financial functions, as well as conditional, date, math, and text formulas.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3#__bkmkalphalist